# Natural coordinates and time integration

Tags: classical-mechanics, integration, mathematics

So I have this physics mechanics dynamics textbook with an example and there is a step I couldn't understand in one of the solution examples. Starting with,

$$ mR \ddot\theta = mg\sin\theta, \tag{1}$$

they multiply both sides with $ \dot\theta $:

$$ mr\dot\theta\ddot\theta = mg\sin\theta\dot\theta. \tag{2}$$

Next step they say they integrate with regard to time:

$$ \frac{1}{2}mR\dot\theta^2 - 0 = -mg\cos\theta + mg\cos0 \tag{3}$$

My question is two parts:

1. Why do they add the $\dot\theta$ to both sides of (2)? Does it make integration easier?
2. How is the integration performed?

Comment: The reason they did that is so integration by parts can be used.

Comment: From the fact there's no $-$ sign in (1), I assume this problem is the inverted problem, not the usual one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The trick has to do with the magic of seeing derivatives as differentials. The first equation can be seen as

\begin{equation}
mR\frac{d\dot{\theta}}{dt}=mgsin\theta
\end{equation}

Multiplication by $\dot{\theta}$ can be seen as $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$. So we get

\begin{equation}
mR\frac{d\dot{\theta}}{dt}\dot{\theta}=mgsin\theta\frac{d\theta}{dt}
\end{equation}

multiplying for $dt$ on both sides we get

\begin{equation}
mR\ d\dot{\theta}\dot{\theta}=mgsin\theta\  d{\theta}
\end{equation}

So now integrating on each side we get the correct answer.

It is a nice trick that is commonly used in physics. It is not very formal but it is useful to avoid integration by parts, which can be messy sometimes.

Comment: -1  There's no reason to bring differentials into it like this.  It's perfectly formal.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The differentials' method is commonly used and it's a useful way of understanding differential equations easily in physics.

Comment: I could edit to say that this is not actually related specifically to differentials but can be done in other ways. I give you that, but the downvote seems a bit excesive.

Comment: Very good actually!
I was fiddling around with the same stuff, but this is really good explanation!

Comment: Note that, w.r.t. Mathjax/LaTeX, $sin$ is viewed as the product of $s$, $i$ and $n$, rather than the trigonometric operator $\sin$ (which you get by writing `\sin`)